# Why are these 2 ARIMA formulations equivalent?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, arima, parameterization

In the "Understanding constants in R" section of his book, Hyndman & Athanasopoulos textbook ["Forecasting: Principles and Practice"](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html) claims that the following AR processes equations are equivalent:

$$(1-\phi_1B-...-\phi_pB^p)(1-B)^dy_t=c$$

$$(1-\phi_1B-...-\phi_pB^p)(1-B)^d(y_t-\mu t^d / d!)=0$$

where $c=\mu(1-\phi_1-...-\phi_p)$, $\mu$ is the mean of $(1-B^d)y_t$ and I've omitted the MA terms as they are the same in both equations.

I can see why this is the case for $d=1$. But why is it generally true? Can you sketch the proof for me?